# How much will this accumulate floating point errors?

Tags: c++, optimization, probability, floating-accuracy

I have a random process that, when called, returns a random number between 0 and K-1, where K may be decently high. I want to keep track of the number of times any outcome occurs, and normalize all the counts into a probability distribution. I want to do this every time I call the random process so that my distribution estimate of the random process is as up-to-date as possible.

A naive approach could be the following:

```
while ( true ) {
    int n = randomProcess();

    ++totalCount;
    ++count[n];
    update();

    do_work_with_updated_prob_vector();
}

void update() {
    for ( int i = 0; i < K; ++i )
        prob[i] = count[i] / static_cast<double>(totalCount);
}
```

However when K starts to become big this approach needs to read the whole count vector at every probability update, which is undesirable due to cache misses and memory access cost. I have devised another solution which is on my limited tests around 30% faster with K~1000. The new update function needs to know the index of the last updated element:

```
void fastUpdate(int id) {
    if ( totalCount == 1 ) {
        prob[id] = 1.0;
        return;
    }
    double newProb = count[id] / static_cast<double>(totalCount - 1);
    double newProbSum = 1.0 + ( newProb - prob[id] );

    prob[id] = newProb;
    for ( int i = 0; i < K; ++i )
        prob[i] /= newProbSum
}
```

This approach works in theory, however I am worried about floating point precision errors that will be accumulating due to the imperfect normalizations that get performed. Should I still call the basic `update` function once in a while to get rid of them? If so, how often? How big can this error become? I have little experience with this sort of problems, and I know that I do not need to underestimate them.

EDIT: Since this seems to be a big deal, I'm going to explain better what I'm doing here so that we may focus more on the problem I stated. I have also updated my first algorithm at the top so that it shows what I am doing better.

I am writing a series of AI algorithms that need to learn an environment that is initially unknown. In this case, the environment is learned by approximating what is seen into a distribution. At each iteration, the algorithm will revise its decisions based on the new data (which not only includes the updated `prob` vector, but also other things). Since these values are not only used, but may also be used multiple times within a single iteration, I would guess that it is better to compute the result once and then use it, which is what I am doing with the update function.

In addition I would like to add that whether I need or not to update the `prob` vector at every iteration or not is truly a non-issue here. The contract of the function `fastUpdate` is that it will do a fast update, and that is where my issue stems from. If I will not need to update so often, I will do that by NOT calling that function at every iteration. Since at the moment I DO need to call it, I am doing it. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your `count` and `totalCount` variables are integers, from which you derive your probabilities whenever you need them, so floating point precision shouldn't be an issue, assuming you use the normal `update` function. Try just calling `update()` once every couple thousand of calls instead of `fastUpdate` and you should have no worries.

Comment: Why do you need to keep a vector with the probabilities updated at all? If you don't need it right now, compute it from the count at the time that you really need it. Computing the thing on demand (e.g. while plotting a graph) won't be noticeable either.

Comment: @AndyG In the first case, that is true. In the fastUpdate function that is not the case though.

Comment: Lest I forget: Using float instead of double halves the memory requirements, which can be beneficial on crowded cachelines!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I do need it right now unfortunately, and that is where the problem stems. About the float, I really do like double precision though! I have lots of probability math so if I can avoid errors by throwing some more space at it I'd like to.

Comment: Okay, so after the update() call, what do you do with the result? If you iterate over the vector a second time, then that is the place where you should look, because there you reload things in the cache that you just had there a few cycles ago.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm not sure I understand what you mean. After the update I may do lots of things, but it definitely can be that I will iterate over the prob vector again. How does that effect my solution?

Comment: Computing this on demand and only storing the count could be much faster as it requires less memory access. Also, thinking about it, not splitting the two vectors would improve locality of data. Both would improve the CPU cache effectivity. Also, I think something with the code is wrong. In the first run, fastUpdate() will divide by `totalCount - 1`, which is zero.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt About the error, you are right thanks, I corrected it now. Unfortunately I may use the prob vector quite I lot, so computing it beforehand really is better. I'm not sure I could I not split them, since if I don't keep track of the counts I will not be able to compute the correct probability on an update.

Comment: You could speed up the on-demand calculation that @UlrichEckhardt recommends by calculating the inverse of the count at every update and using a multiply instead of a divide. Multiplies are really fast on modern processors.

Comment: @MarkRansom Not sure why are you focusing on that, but as I explained I DO need to compute prob every time since I am going to use that. If that was not true, then I would simply avoid calling the update() function.

Comment: You say computing it beforehand really is better, but you don't explain why. The only thing you *do* say is that for large `K` it takes too long. If it's just a matter of code cleanliness you can hide your accesses in an inline method of a class that does the multiply for you every time you request a number from the array.

Comment: @MarkRansom This is part of an AI algorithm that is supposed to learn in realtime the best possible action for an environment that it does not know in advance. To do so, every time the AI algorithm acts, it needs to update its knowledge of the environment and update its reasoning with the new information. The algorithm uses probability estimates for outcomes extensibly, and so I prefer to precompute such values since it will be faster.

Comment: How large could totalCount get?

Comment: @amdn Tens of millions

Comment: You say precomputing values will be faster and your question is entirely about he fact that it isn't faster. This isn't making much sense.

Comment: If improving locality may speed things up, consider interleaving counts and probs with a struct `struct D { int cnt; double prob; D() : cnt(0), prob(0) {}};` then declare array `D data[K];` and use `D[i].cnt` and `D[i].prob` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a for instance, take this python example:

```
for i in range(1000000):
    x = rnd.randrange(0,10)
    intar.append(x)
    dblar.append(x/100.0)
intsum = 0
for i in intar:
    intsum += i
dblsum = 0.0
for d in dblar:
    dblsum += d
print("int: %f, dbl: %f, diff: %f" % ((intsum/100.0), dblsum, ((intsum/100.0)-dblsum)))
```

yields:

```
int: 45012.230000, dbl: 45012.200000, diff: 0.030000
```

Now, I forced a divisor to be sure that there would be consistent rounding errors. I'm guessing that the nature of your input data distribution would be critical to determining how much errors will accumulate; though I never new or have forgotten the maths necessary to derive an answer. With the exact behavior of the floating point math being known based on compiler options, it should be possible to derive the range of errors given an idea of the input data.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know this, as both the generative process and the code that utilizes the results may be extremely varied. Is there a way to obtain some worst case behaviour?

Comment: I'm sure there is. However, that is well beyond my math foo. Were it me, I'd just try to benchmark some likely cases and see. For situations that *really* matter, you might ask on "MathOverflow" (one of StackExchange's sites) or another similar place.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than update `prob` when you add items, update it when you need to read the probabilities. Use a boolean flag to indicate whether or not `prob` needs updating before you read from it.

```
while ( true ) {
    int n = randomProcess();

    ++totalCount;
    ++count[n];
    dirty = true;
}

void updateBeforeRead() {
    if(dirty) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < K; ++i )
            prob[i] = count[i] / static_cast<double>(totalCount);
        }
        dirty = false;
    }
}
```

If your usage flips between a large number of samples followed by a large number of calculations based on the probabilities then this should be efficient whilst limiting rounding issues.

Comment: Please see my edit, but the idea is that I'm not updating `prob` for no reason, but because I'm actually using the updated values.

Comment: @Svalorzen: If your calculations are happening at the same frequency as your observations, are you sure that updating `prob` on the fly with `fastUpdate` is more efficient than computing the probabilities on the fly with `static_cast<double>(count[i])/static_cast<double>(totalCount)`?

Comment: Well, very likely I need to reuse all updated values multiple times (it depends on the problem and what is happening) so it seems to me that updating prob once and then just using it is better than computing over and over the division? And since updating prob is faster than computing the probabilities (I tested this), I assumed it was a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Second attempt...

Given that your testing has indicated that updating `prob` directly improves performance for your algorithm you can minimise rounding errors by resetting it *periodically*.

```
void fastUpdate(int id) {
    if ( totalCount == 1 ) {
        prob[id] = 1.0;
        fastUpdates = 0;
        return;
    }

    if(fastUpdates<maxFastUpdates) {
        double newProb = count[id] / static_cast<double>(totalCount - 1);
        double newProbSum = 1.0 + ( newProb - prob[id] );

        prob[id] = newProb;
        for ( int i = 0; i < K; ++i )
            prob[i] /= newProbSum;

        ++fastUpdates;
    }
    else {
     update();
     fastUpdates = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: My (only) questions in my post were: "Should I still call the basic update function once in a while to get rid of them? If so, how often? How big can this error become?". If you could provide some insight on this, it would be welcome. I know that I can call `update` directly to remove the errors, however I don't really have any intuition for how often I should do so.

Comment: @Svalorzen: Apologies for my misreading. You're facing a single rounding error for each arithmetic operation. Roughly speaking, the elements of `prob` will accumulate three double precision epsilon multiplicative rounding errors after each `fastUpdate` (two in `newProbSum` and one in the division, assuming no cancellation error). Your decision as to when to reset should be driven by how many of these you are willing to tolerate.

Comment: @Svalorzen: My gut feeling is that a reset after 1000 fast updates would be a reasonable trade off, but you'll need to run plenty of tests before you make your decision.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely do it. Do you have any suggestion as to what may be some edge cases I may want to examine? (as in, they may yield the worst results?)

Comment: @Svalorzen: Your worst case arises if `newProbSum` is near zero, but given the nature of your problem I think that it's unlikely that you'll run into it (I've not actually gone through the maths, so take this with a pinch of salt).

Answer (score 0):

The fastest operation is the operation you don't perform. Even if you end up using every single value produced after every single update, you'll save if you don't have to write the updated values back to memory. You can also shave a few clocks by doing multiplies instead of divides. It's quite possible that the multiply is faster than the memory access you saved.

```
template<int K>
class Prob
{
private:
    int count[K];
    int totalCount;
    double multiplier;
public:
    update(int id)
    {
        ++count[id];
        ++totalCount;
        multiplier = 1.0 / totalCount;
    }
    double operator[](int id)
    {
        return count[id] * multiplier;
    }
};

Prob<K> prob;
while ( true ) {
    int n = randomProcess();

    prob.update(n);

    // demo
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
        sum += prob[i];

    do_work_with_updated_prob_vector(prob);
}
```